# static UI analysis with my own grammar rules (want to make eclipse android visual UI guidelines checker)

Tags: android, xml, grammar, analysis, ui-guidelines

I want to make eclipse plugin or standalone app that will help user to check if android xml layout files are according to android user interface guidelines (that I have added earlier from). User can also input his own guidelines into existed grammar rules. Also he can choose some UI guidelines patterns (ones that is created for his company or some existed ones). What's the best approach to develop this app? What's the easiest and fastest way? Which language/approach I should choose? Can you provide me if possible with some tutorials/books/examples for this? I have found that it could be done with JavaCC(but it's difficult,user should edit/create grammar rules). Also I have found some recommendations to do it with DSL(Domain specific languages), code generators but I don't know how to do this.
I am doing UI checker for my master thesis. It should enable general code analysis in next phases - for some other students (thesis) to continue with this project (tracking navigation, coding style,etc). I am doing part which checks xml files with my grammar rules(which can be added,edited by users) and shows visually in gui editor where is warning(font too big, colors not compatible, etc.). My checker would work for android, but other students will make it for ios and windows phone.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This tool already exists, it is called 'Lint' and already is built and executed automatically by the Android IDEs:
http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

The tool is designed to allow you to add your own custom rules and checks:
http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check

There are other static analysis tools (PMD, FindBugs, etc) that can also be used with Eclipse already, that could also be extended for your purposes.  I don't think you want to create your own plugin, but should extend the existing tools.

Comment: I am doing UI checker for my master thesis. It should enable general code analysis in next phases - for some other students (thesis) to continue with this project (tracking navigation, coding style,etc). I am doing part which checks xml files with my grammar rules(which can be added,edited by users) and shows visually in gui editor where is warning(font too big, colors not compatible, etc.). My checker would work for android, but other students will make it for ios and windows phone. It doesn't have to be eclipse plugin, it can be standalone app. I guess you can now help me even more.